# Go to a file (gf) while replacing the current buffer

Tags: vim

I want to `gf` in vim and immediately forget where I `gf`'ed from (delete that buffer/replace it with the file I'm `gf`ing into).
I'd like to do this often.

**Unecessary Details:**
I want to navigate my source-controlled project tree somewhat efficiently.
Command-T segfaults on me and I don't have time to debug it. What I came up with is

```
 "create new buffer and read a filtered project tree into it
 :enew | cd `git-pwd` | r !git ls-files | grep MYFILTER
 "(git-pwd is a wrapper around `git rev-parse --show-cdup` that replaces empty output with ./ )
```

This gives me a `grep`-filtered repo tree from whence I can "gf" to the particular file I want. Doing this often accumulates them unnamed buffers, though. I'm not very eager to learn VimScript and make myself a proper plugin just yet.

Comment: Vim Fugitive + Vim Pathogen fit the bill perfectly. Both plugins   are by Tim Pope

Comment: CtrlP is better than Command-T and it's written in VimScript, so the likelihood of it segfaulting is very low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `,gf` mapping should do the trick. When you change files, the previous one is set as the *alternate file*, which you can conveniently `:bdelete` (or `:bwipeout`, whatever you prefer) via the `#` symbol.

```
:nnoremap <silent> ,gf gf:bdelete #<CR>
```